# Don't submit flag or close vote immediately on tapping reason in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, vote-to-close, ios-app

The current process for flagging or voting to close in the iOS app is very susceptible to fat-fingering. A list is presented, and as soon as you tap an item from that list, that's accepted as your selection, and your flag or vote is submitted.

The interface should instead include a "submit flag/vote" button, as the dialog on the web site does.

Comment: We totally need this on the Android app, too.

Comment: I'm working on this. This will be available sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the app (1.0.1) now has a button to confirm your selection.

[image: Flagging confirmation button]

Comment: Shouldn't it say close when voting to close?